# sql - how do I remove half of the characters from a column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

I have an table column filled with usersIDs from a survey, but somehow the userID was written twice in each record. like below

```
UserID
========
35863586
12341234
321321
```

I've seen Aaron Alton's suggestion about removing certain characters, but in my case, I'll have to remove half of whatever the ID is to get it right because sometime the id is 8 digit sometimes 6 digits.

So this wouldn't help much,

```
SELECT RIGHT(MyColumn, LEN(MyColumn) - 4) AS MyTrimmedColumn
```

Can someone suggested a way to solve my problem please?

Thanks very much

Comment: Thanks JW.

Sorry that I asked a question so ... this is what happens when I'm getting up too early... I'll see if I can go back and learn some mathematics again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

since you have mentioned that the length is 6 and sometimes 8,

divide the length by two

```
SELECT RIGHT(MyColumn, LEN(MyColumn) - (LEN(MyColumn) / 2)) AS MyTrimmedColumn
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a4f5b/2)

or simply

```
SELECT UserID, RIGHT(UserID, (LEN(UserID) / 2)) AS MyTrimmedColumn
FROM   table1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a4f5b/3)

Comment: Hi JW. 

I just found that datatype of UserID is float and the id number's quite big like '23261982326198,12409551240955,752300752300,22754212275421'.So myTrimmed column value look quite strange after running the query...
--------------------------
Custom Data 
23261982326198 
---
MyTrimmedColumn
e+013

Comment: try casting it, `CAST(UserID AS VARCHAR(20))`

Comment: `RIGHT(CAST(UserID AS VARCHAR(20)), (LEN(CAST(UserID AS VARCHAR(20))) / 2))`

Comment: @Ray float is slightly difficult to update but here's somekind-of-a-mess solution: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/08035/5

Comment: haha, your solution works! I've never thought of converting it to decimal first. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
update IDtable
set ID = LEFT(ID,(LEN(ID)/2))
```

This should update all of the columns with the correct string.